# Instance of 'Future<GroupBy>' in flutter code

Tags: flutter

from the original code I can't get the same result
here is the original code

```
 loadPreviousEvents() {
    mySelectedEvents = {
      "2022-09-13": [
        {"eventDescp": "11", "eventTitle": "111"},
        {"eventDescp": "22", "eventTitle": "22"}
      ],
      "2022-09-30": [
        {"eventDescp": "22", "eventTitle": "22"}
      ],
      "2022-09-20": [
        {"eventTitle": "ss", "eventDescp": "ss"}
      ]
    };
    print(mySelectedEvents);
  }
```

I want to retrieve the same thing from my database

here is what i tried without success

```
@override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _selectedDate = _focusedDay;

    loadPreviousEvents();
  }

  Future<void> loadPreviousEvents() async {
    final res = await dbRequest();
    print(res);
    final mySelectedEvents = (res.map((e) => GroupBy.fromJson(e))).toList();
    print(mySelectedEvents);
  }

  Future<List<dynamic>> dbRequest() async {
    var url = 'http://xxxxxxxxxx/getEvents.php';
    var res = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    var response = json.decode(res.body);
    return response;

  }
```

with     `print(mySelectedEvents);`
i have :

```
 [Instance of 'GroupBy', Instance of 'GroupBy', Instance of 'GroupBy', Instance of 'GroupBy', Instance of 'GroupBy']
```

print(res);

```
[{date: 2022-09-17, eventDescp: azerty, eventTitle: azertyui}, {date: 2022-09-17, eventDescp: 11, eventTitle: AZE}, {date: 2022-09-17, eventDescp: 22, eventTitle: 4556}, {date: 2022-09-20, eventDescp: 77, eventTitle: HHJ}, {date: 2022-09-17, eventDescp: 44, eventTitle: BYYY}]
```

Comment: You need to overwrite toString method in your GroupBy class

Comment: replace toString with what

Answer (score 0):

my model
import 'dart:convert';

```
class GroupBy {
  GroupBy({
    this.id,
    this.date,
    this.selectdate,
    this.descript,
    this.title,
    this.idEventDate,
  });

  final int? id;
  final DateTime? date;
  final DateTime? selectdate;
  final String? descript;
  final String? title;
  final int? idEventDate;

  factory GroupBy.fromRawJson(String str) => GroupBy.fromJson(json.decode(str));

  String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

  factory GroupBy.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => GroupBy(
        id: json["id"] == null ? null : json["id"],
        date: json["date"] == null ? null : DateTime.parse(json["date"]),
        selectdate: json["selectdate"] == null
            ? null
            : DateTime.parse(json["selectdate"]),
        descript: json["descript"] == null ? null : json["descript"],
        title: json["title"] == null ? null : json["title"],
        idEventDate:
            json["id_event_date"] == null ? null : json["id_event_date"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id == null ? null : id,
        "date": date == null
            ? null
            : "${date!.year.toString().padLeft(4, '0')}-${date!.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${date!.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}",
        "selectdate": selectdate == null
            ? null
            : "${selectdate!.year.toString().padLeft(4, '0')}-${selectdate!.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${selectdate!.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}",
        "descript": descript == null ? null : descript,
        "title": title == null ? null : title,
        "id_event_date": idEventDate == null ? null : idEventDate,
      };
}
```